# Jboss6 not starting up - Error message

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have a small issue here. I installed Jboss-6.1.0 and when I run the 'run' bat file, JBoss does not get started and I get this error. (Please refer the attached)

[image: Error Message]

My OS is Windows 8.1.I have set my Path and Java_Home variables correctly.Is there any more configuration to do?

A help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same problem although with java 1.8. These are the steps I followed.

1.Go to the “bin” directory where you’ve installed JBoss

2.Edit the “run.bat” file

3.Search for the line “

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:%DIRNAME%logging.properties %JAVA_OPTS%“
    Change the %DIRNAME%
```

to your absolute path to the “bin” directory of your installed JBoss.e.g.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME% -Dlogging.configuration=file:”C:\Java\jboss-6.1.0-final\bin\logging.properties” %JAVA_OPTS%
```

I do not think the java version difference would affect the solution. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Installed a different server but tried your solution and it worked!